# In FB Permissions: Locale / Location - What is the difference?

Tags: permissions, facebook, fbconnect

What is the difference beteen locale (basic info) and user_location (permission)? See [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

+What are some examples for both? how far down do they each go in the US? state? city?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locale specifies the interface language in which Facebook is displayed to the user.

Location is the user's current city